# How can I uninstall or force a reinstall of DirectX in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, directx

My DirectX installation has become corrupt and apparently the installer doesn't reinstall because it thinks everything is fine. How can I uninstall DirectX or force a reinstall?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the native directx11 or the directx runtime? If you're not sure, run dxdiag from the run command in the startmenu, it will tell you the version number on the front page. It will also let you test various aspects of the directx subsystem.

Comment: I am running dxdiag but it pops up various error messages. The version it reports is DirectX 11.

Comment: Apparently the only thing that can revert a DX installation is a piece of software that costs $20, and I'd rather just reformat.